# .Net Core Upgrade To 5 - Version doesn't map to a known HTTP protocol

Tags: asp.net-core

We upgraded our asp.net core 3.1 web app to version 5. It's hosted in IIS. All servers are fine. We go to production and we can't stay stable because of the following error at the bottom. Just flurry of errors so we had to roll back until we can resolve this issue.

Looking at the breaking changes from 3.1 to 5 - I'm still not spotting anything. Looking at the Microsoft source code I'm still not sure how the error would come about. Any help would be appreciated.

```
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Version doesn't map to a known HTTP protocol. (Parameter 'version')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpProtocol.GetHttpProtocol(Version version)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpRequestFeature.get_Protocol()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.IsEmptyHostAllowed(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Comment: This article may answer you:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32775

Comment: Looking at this. I saw the github issue as well. This means people or some device is using .9 http which is over 20 years old? There was a ton of errors so that  can't be actual users - maybe proxy or health checks or somethign? Most browsers are using http 1.1. I guess I will turn logging on to debug to gather more info. We pushed api's using .net core 5 no issues. This is the first web app.

Comment: @user1717926 - Did you solve this in any way? We are receiving this since our update to .NET 5. As you mentioned it's probably a health-check, But it seems to occur before custom middlewares and thus difficult to log.

Comment: No, we kind of punted this a bit since .Net Core 6 will be out soon and they have that fix that Chaodeng mentioned above. I went through the Microsoft source code and it is low in the stack. I can't find a way around it so we don't throw a ton of errors. The issue we are facing does appear to be that issue.